# Cat with heredoc does not work in zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh, cat, heredoc

When I try

```
cat > myfile << EOF
TEST TEXT
EOF
```

I just get an empty file. The same using `echo` command. What's going on?
I can only think about something conflicting in the `.zshenv` profile file, but I have no idea about what it could be...

I am using `zsh 4.3.6 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`.

**Update**
It now works with `zsh 5.0.5 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Works for me in zsh 4.3.9.

Comment: works for me in Zsh 5.0.5. Please start zsh with `zsh -f` and retry. `zsh -f` is to ignore any configuration files you have, i.e. that is a zsh with all configs at default values.

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way to write it:

```
cat <<eos > filename
foo bar baz
eos
```

That works in zsh.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your /tmp (or wherever your `$TMPDIR` points) were read-only.

You should be able to discover what's wrong by attaching strace to the zsh you're running the above from, using e.g. `strace -ff -s200 -o /tmp/zsh.log -p PID-goes-here` from a different shell.